# Possibility of changing the rulers positions in QGIS layout?

Tags: qgis, layouts

[image]Is there any possibility of swapping the rulers in the QGIS-Layout section in a way that my zero point would be located in the bottom left of my screen? Maybe it would feel a bit easier to set my guidelines when calculating where to put them.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of your current layout? Because basically you can arrange the layout as you wish.

Comment: The screenshot should now be available to you...thanks for you trying to help me though...just started learning QGIS a week ago...:)

Comment: As far as I know there are no setting in the options to set the position or the unit of the ruler

Comment: Hmm okay, still thanks for trying to help, hope you have a pleasant weekend!

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the rulers at the sides. Those are (as stated) fixed. Still, you can place elements in your map by entering exact mm values.